# Update Salesforce record with where condition from field

Tags: rest-api, salesforce1-app, update, patch

We have custom object where we have custom field as status as open, inProgress and close.

We are creating this custom object record using connected app via REST API. We are updating the fields as we go into the connected app using the created record ID.

But we want to make sure we only update the record if the status is inProgress only.

The other thing is we are reluctant to make multiple calls like we GET first, then check the status and then we make another update calls.

We are trying to find something where we could do this in a single call with where condition.

We have checked **/services/data/v51.0/composite/batch** & **/services/data/v51.0/sobjects/customerObject__c/hjksdh0890980**  but not able to mention the where status = "inProgress"

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think what you want to do with OOTB REST APIs will work as there is no expression language to use in either the Batch or Composite Graph resources

To do this in a single call, you can code a custom Apex REST service that takes in a POST payload looking something like this:

```
{
 "id" : "theCustomObjectId",
 "field1" : "newValueForField1",
 "field2" : "newValueForField2",
 ...}
```

Or, the payload can look like the Sobject being updated with the properties mapping exactly to SObject field names

Regardless, the apex rest service queries the Custom Object based on supplied Id and, if `In Progress`, applies the updates using DML `update` statement.  Otherwise, the ApexRest service simply does nothing, returning a status code

You can read up on [Apex Rest services](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.206.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_rest_intro.htm) or, here, on [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_integration_services/apex_integration_webservices)

Answer (score 0):

While your question gives limited info; I have tried my best to answer.

You should be able to set a flag to notify that it is coming from a Connected App(a custom field of type checkbox can do this.). You can check it in before update trigger and if the Status is "In Progress" and the Flag is "true" then use Record.AddError() so that you get a response and can handle that at your end.

Comment: Thanks @khushal. 
But this is what we are trying to do 
update customeObject__c 
set custom_field_c = "John"
where status__c = "inProgress" and id = Ahfy5646575

By doing this we don't have to make multiple calls:
First query the record 
Select status__c from customeObject__c
where id = Ahfy5646575

if status__c = "inProgress"

Then use POST/Patch API to update the record using the ID.

Else Display error that update not allowed.

Please let me know if you need more details.

The solution you suggested will still require us to make 2 above. And we want to avoid that.